# Error while converting a file into byte array in android

Tags: java, android, file, arrays

I want to pick a file from file manager and i have to convert it into byte[] and send it through Ksoap2 webservice.But unfortunately error occurs while converting file into byte[]. Here is my code.

```
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
       Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 2) {


        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
         FilePath=selectedImageUri.toString();



        FilePath=selectedImageUri.toString();
       //    uploadFile();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            File imagefile = new File(FilePath);
            Log.e("FilePath",FilePath);
            String byteArrayStr = "";
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("FIle Not found" +FilePath, "");
            }

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, baos);

            byte[] data1 = baos.toByteArray();
            totalSize = data1.length;

            String strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data1, 
            0).toString();
            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, 
              "InsertFile");
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new
             SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);              
                MarshalBase64 marshal = new MarshalBase64();
                marshal.register(envelope);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                request.addProperty("FromUsername", 
                   LoginActivity.username.toString());
                request.addProperty("ToUsername",name[1]);
                request.addProperty("filetype", ".png");
                request.addProperty("f", data1);
                HttpTransportSE AndroidHttpTransportSE = new 
             HttpTransportSE(URL);
                try {
                    AndroidHttpTransportSE.call(NAMESPACE + 
                    "InsertFile",envelope);
                    // http://scm.org/UserDetails
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) 
                     envelope.getResponse();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No file 
           }}}
```

This is my OnActivityResult() method and here i have received the file which i have chosen from my device using Intent.createChooser[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcFqb.png)
For reference here is my logcat. Please resolve this error.

Comment: error log clearly shows your data is null

Comment: can you please give me a piece of code to get a file path?I think the way im getting the path of a file is wrong.

Comment: What is the path you're trying to access?

Comment: I need to access a path of a file which i have been chosen. A path like this file:///storage/sdcard/newFolder/Image.png.

Comment: Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImage);

Comment: Cannot resolve the method getPath().

Comment: public String getPath(Uri uri) {
  String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
  Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
  int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(column_index);

 }